# Yii display multiple Child elements as links in a CGridView Field

Tags: php, activerecord, gridview, yii

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE "place" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('place_id_seq'::regclass),
    "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    "parent" int8,
    "description" varchar(100)
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
```

(It's PostgreSQL but this shouldn't be relevant here)

I created the CRUD through giix and changed a bit the relations to match my needs. So I ended up with:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'parent0' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Places', 'parent'),
        'places' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Places', 'parent'),
    );
}
```

The goal here is that a place can belong to another place and have multiple children places.

My problem is that I need to change the admin action to match the following grid:
[image: Print manipulated by the inspector to reflect the desired behaviour]

Print manipulated by the inspector to reflect the desired behaviour

So my problem is to get the list of all the children objects and display it as a list of links. I tried change the respective admin.php view file for:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'places-grid',
    'dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider('Places', array('id'=>$model->places)),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
                'name'=>'parent',
                'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->parent0)',
                'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(Places::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
                ),
        'name',
        'places',
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

But this, as expected, throughs an error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Also I don't know this would even work with the built in avanced search.

Could anyone kindly point me into the correct direction here?

Comment: all your queries already have solutions here on S.O, handle them one at a time, first make filter show up correctly, then go for making the search work, then the links. use s.o. search and you'll find the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much search I found a way to solve my problem. Not sure if it's the best way but it works nicely:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'places-grid',
    'dataProvider' => new CActiveDataProvider('Places', array('id'=>$model->places)),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        array(
                'name'=>'parent',
                'value'=>'GxHtml::valueEx($data->parent0)',
                'filter'=>GxHtml::listDataEx(Places::model()->findAllAttributes(null, true)),
                ),
        'name',
        array(
        'header'=>'Children',
        'type'=>'html',
                'value'=> function($data) {
                    $placesLinks = array();
                    foreach ($data->places as $place) {
                        $placesLinks[] = GxHtml::link(GxHtml::encode(GxHtml::valueEx($place, 'name')), array('places/view', 'id' => GxActiveRecord::extractPkValue($place, true)));
                    }
                    return implode(', ', $placesLinks);
                }
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

This uses Giix. If you don't use that then you'll have to change the link generation accordingly.

Cheers

Comment: good that you got your own solution working, for search see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4865411/720508)